# Git p4 branches

Tags: git, perforce, git-p4

I have a project based in
`//Engineering/qwerty/baseline/servers/ApplicationServer/`
and branch
`//Engineering/qwerty/branches/rtf/`

How can I do one git repo with
`master => //Engineering/qwerty/baseline/servers/ApplicationServer/`
and branch `rtf => //Engineering/qwerty/branches/rtf/`
?

Answer (score 0):

Maybe:

```
git clone //Engineering/qwerty/baseline/servers/ApplicationServer
cd ApplicationServer
git sync --branch refs/remotes/p4/rtf //Engineering/qwerty/branches/rtf
```

But I haven't tried it.

From http://git-scm.com/docs/git-p4